# What colums to index for a JOIN with WHERE

Tags: sql, join, indexing

Assume you have a `JOIN` with a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     partners
JOIN     orders 
    ON   partners.partner_id = orders.partner_id
WHERE    orders.date 
    BETWEEN 20140401 AND 20140501
```

1) An index on `partner_id` in both tables will speed up the `JOIN`, right?
2) An index on `orders.date` will speed up the `WHERE` clause?
3) But as far as I know, one `SELECT` can not use more than one index. So which one will be used?

Comment: Please see the execution Plan, I think both Index will be used. I dont think that Optimizer uses only one Index at a time.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the backticks in the SQL statement.

Comment: partners.partner_id is (presumably) a PRIMARY KEY, so that's already indexed. A compound index on (orders.partner_id,orders.date) [or the reverse] will likely be optimal.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not mysql, mostly Oracle and DB6

Comment: So why did you use MySQL specific syntax if you are not using MySQL? And what is DB6?

Comment: the qouotes were accident, and I meant DB2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query, with the quoting fixed (and assuming `orders.date` is really a date type):

```
SELECT *
FROM partners JOIN
     orders
     ON partners.partner_id = orders.partner_id
WHERE orders.date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-05-01';
```

For inner join, there are basically two execution strategies.  The engine can start with the partners table and find all matches in orders.  Or it can start with orders can find all matches in partners.  (There are then different algorithms that can be used.)

For the first approach, the only index what would help is `orders(partner_id, orderdate)`.  For the second approach, the best index is `orders(orderdate, partner_id)`.  Note that these are not equivalent.

In most scenarios like this, I would expect the orders table to be larger and the filtering to be important.  That would suggest that the best execution plan is to start with the `orders` table and filter it first, using the second option.

Comment: your backticks have gone haywire.. you need the `.` to be outside the the backticks in `table.column` and the timestamps should not have them as they are not column names.

Comment: @Arth . . . Thank you, it is now fixed.  I just copied the OP's original query and didn't even look at the quoting, I was looking at the structure of the logic.

Comment: I figured that's what happened, I upvoted anyway because of the logic, I agree the second situation is way more likely. I'd probably pass those timestamps as integers not strings though.

Answer (score 2):

To start, an index is used for an **operator** not  for the **SELECT** statement. Therefore one index will be used for reading data from the `partner` table and another index could be used to get data from `orders` table.

I think that the best strategy in this case would be to have a clustered index on `partners.partner_id` and one non-clustered index on `orders.partner_id` and `orders.date`

Answer (score 0):

See the case. It is a sample case

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    [dbo].[LUEducation] E
JOIN    LUCitizen C On C.skCitizen = E.skCitizen
WHERE   C.skCitizen <= 100 
AND     E.skSchool = 26069
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

The sql engine uses more than 1 index at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which DBMS you are using it's difficult to know what execution plan the optimizer is going to choose.

Here's a typical one:

> Do a range scan on orders.date, using a sorted index for that purpose.
>   Do a loop join on the results,  doing one lookup on
>   partners.partner_id for each entry, using the index on that field.

In this plan, an index on orders.partner_id will not be used.

However, if the WHERE clause were not there, you might see an execution plan that

> does a merge join using the indexes on partners.partner_id and
>   orders.partner_id.

This terminology may be confusing, because the documentation for your DBMS may use different terms.

Answer (score 0):

One select can only use one index **per table** (index-merge is an exception).
You pointed out the right indexes in your question.
You don't really need an index on orders.partner_id for this query, 
but it is necessary for foreign key constraints and join in other direction.